# Why does the redis-server take too long to load in memory the database at boot?

Tags: python, yocto, redis

My Linux distribution uses the `redis` database.
At boot the `redis-server` needs about 80 seconds to load the dataset. The following is a log that shows what I have written:

```
redis-server[249]: 249:M 17 Oct 2022 16:29:55.173 * DB loaded from append only file: 79.442 seconds
```

If a Python program tries querying the database before the `redis-server` has finished the loading in memory operation, it is raised the Exception: `redis.exceptions.BusyLoadingError`.
The Exception description is: `Redis is loading the dataset in memory` and is compliant with the context that I have described (that is the database is loading data in memory).

Because I'm using the default configuration of `redis-server` in this moment I don't know exactly what is the type of persistence used by `redis-server`.
The file `redis.conf` is very long so, here, I report settings that I think are most important:

```
...
########################### SNAPSHOTTING  ###########################
#
# Save the DB on disk:
#
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.

# OE: tune for a small embedded system with a limited # of keys.
save 120 1
save 60 100
save 30 1000

######################### APPEND ONLY MODE #########################
# OE: changed default to enable this
appendonly yes

# The name of the append only file (default: "appendonly.aof")
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
...
```

These settings (in particular `appendonly yes`) seem indicate that the persistence type used by the database is: `Append Only File` (`AOF`).
I think these settings are causing this long loading time.

Is it possible to use settings that avoid a too long loading time at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely because your redis-server process is configured to use the append-only file, and you never sent the `BGREWRITEAOF` command.

The Redis Manual on the redis.io website has a good writeup of the four different persistence (data recovery) configurations:  https://redis.io/docs/manual/persistence/.  The append-only file is merely one of the options.

It's not a *bad* option, it simply requires a little maintenance, or else, as you have discovered, it makes the process start slowly.  Read about the options and their benefits/drawbacks and pick the one that's best for your usage patterns.

Comment: thanks. I'll study your suggestions and I'll give you a feedback. Any other pratical hints are accepted!

Comment: Thanks, with `BGREWRITEAOF` the time of loading data in memory has been greatly reduced.

Comment: I have found this [useful link](https://github.com/sourcegraph/sourcegraph/issues/3300) which explains how to use the `BGREWRITEAOF` command.

Comment: Yes, if you read the persistence doc page I liked to in my answer, farther down the page is a description of some `auto-aof-rewrite-percentage` settings.  And there's the source doc page for the `BGREWRITEAOF` command itself:  https://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof/