# Remove temporary files from disk caused by Redis command BGREWRITEAOF

Tags: redis

### Context description

My Linux distribution contains redis-server 6.0.5. Redis is configured to use persistence `AOF` (Append Only File) and the `RDB` persistence is disabled.

At boot a script requests to redis-server the execution of `BGREWRITEAOF` command. This request starts a process (with PID=`<pid>`) which creates a file `temp-rewriteaof-<pid>.aof` in the same data Redis path where is written the `appendonly.aof` file.

This is the normal working of `BGREWRITEAOF` command. The usefulness of this command is proved by what it's written in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721321/why-does-the-redis-server-take-too-long-to-load-in-memory-the-database-at-boot).

### What's the problem

The problem comes when the system is switch off while the `BGREWRITEAOF` is not completed. In this case the file `temp-rewriteaof-<pid>.aof` is still present at reboot and it takes up space on the disk.

Because the system can be switch off in every moment I risk that my disk can become full.
In my opinion, the unique solution for this problem is to create a script that remove all files `temp-rewriteaof-*.aof` from the data Redis folder.

### Question

Does someone know a better solution? Redis has got a **clean** procedure/command for solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis-server does not have sophisticated methods of managing the disk space on the server where it's running.  It manages its own RDB snapshot files and the AOF file (as you described).  However, managing files that were created by a previous process interrupted by a computer halt is not something Redis does.

I would suggest you add a routine to the boot-time script you wrote that sends the `BGREWRITEAOF` command to the Redis server.  The routine would clean out any stale temporary AOF file that was left behind by the previous server halt.  It's a good place for this routine - the script is already concerned with AOF file management, and boot time is an appropriate time to prepare for the next hours/days of the computer running (and consuming disk space) by cleaning up stale files.

Comment: Thanks, you confirm exactly what I said in the question. I think that I can request the cleaning of the `temp` files before executing the command `BGREWRITEAOF` in this way the cleaning and the command not can be in conflict.